# How to bind taxonomy term set to list column in sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, splistitem, term-set, taxonomyfieldvalue

I have created a `term set` in SharePoint. I would like to show items from that `term set` in one of list columns. How do I bind this term store later **manually** to list column.

[image: Taxonomy field]

This is field of type `TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti` where I want to bind term set.

Currently it shows nothing.